# How would I Select a simple table from sql and display it on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to SELECT a user from a table using the WHERE clause.  I know how to write the query, but how do I execute it and how do I match the UserId with the current one (how do I know what the current userid is using the login controls)?  I basically want to display profile information by selecting the table and matching it to the userid.  Thanks.

Comment: Data access is a big topic, with a myriad of different routes. What data access tools are you using at the moment (if any)? And what is available? For example, is LINQ-to-whatever an option?

Comment: @Anyhony: i wish you would stop ending all titles with "ASP.NET C#". It's already in the tags!

Comment: @John Saunders Sorry, I am new on stackoverflow, I will definitely stop

Comment: @Marc Gravell I am using the basic data access tools: System.Data.SqlClient, with the simple SqlCommand command.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic answer i can give, given the lack of information on database, tools etc. Is to learn the rules of ado.net.

http://www.asp101.com/articles/jay/adodotnet/default.asp

this site is a good place to start. The principal is connection, command, then do something with that command( as far as i see it) As Marc has commented, if you are looking at data access there are thousands of options, Linq is a great new way to go however, for more complex situations you may need to mix and match.

To get started with linq i would go to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx
and plough through. However, this may not be what you were asking at all, in which case- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as possible:

You'll need a method which `Opens` a `Connection` to the database, executes a `Command` on it and then returns some data to a `DataReader` or `Dataset`.

Your SQL command is going to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myUserTable Where UserId = x
```

So your application will need to pass the current user's ID to the database.

I would use a repeater on the front end to display the user information from the table.

Simple example here: http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp

HTH